# Why does C preserves both goto and while, involving tail recursion

Tags: c, recursion, scheme, sicp

**Tail recursion** performs the same effect as **goto**. Or to say, in lang C, *while* and *goto* substitute the role of tail recursion in Scheme. What made designers decided to preserve both *goto* and *while* implementations in C? As I think people hardly ever use 'goto' in actual situations.

If *goto* and *while* are to make up the fault that C cannot implement **iteration** by writing in a **recursive** way, are they in same special construction? - to avoid normal recursion. (just as 'cond' differs 'if' in Scheme) Is this problem related to the reason why they preserve both words?

Comment: What makes you think that C cannot implement tail recursion?..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think he meant to say that you can't write tail calls in C and *expect* them to be optimized into taking no stack space. Unlike scheme, C does not guarantee TCO.

Comment: Thank @delnan for help explain. I think it is compiler who does the work to optimize tail recursion for C, and I can't find the procedure directly in C code.

Comment: A C compiler makes assembly code. Assembly (x86) has cmp,conditional jumps and unconditional jmps. The constructs if, while, for and goto has to be converted to the assembly primitives. Gcc supports tail recursion, BUT there is no such requirement in C(++) specs (like Common LISP spec)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tail *recursion* is not a replacement for `goto`. Tail *calls* are, if you also have first-class functions (which C doesn't have either).

> What made designers decided to preserve both goto and while implements in C?

Without `while` (and `for`, to a slightly lesser extent), you can't do structured programming properly - `goto` is rarely the best way to express control flow. It's still useful to have `goto` (at least in the context of C) as it can express some patterns for which there's no built-in control flow constructor more clearly and efficiently. For example, it yields easier and reliable clean up on function exit than repeating the clean up at every possible exit point.

If C had scheme-like macros, perhaps it could do fine with just one primitive, `goto`, with all loop constructs built on top of `goto` as macros. But C doesn't have such macros, for good reasons (and some not so good reasons).

Comment: Excuse me for one more confusion: tail recursion is not a replacement for goto, how? What difference is it? As they do similar work.

Comment: @cloudr3414 Tail recursion can only emulate `goto start_of_current_function;` not `goto anywhere_in_the_program`. A prime example is continuation passing style, where you have tons of tail calls but virtually none of them are *recursive* calls. You can of course emulate the latter with some variables and conditions, but it adds extra computation and space cost.